# count the days from a specific date js + link to html

Tags: javascript, html

im having trouble displaying the result of this code into my html file. 
the goal i try to achieve is to make a counter for the days from a specific date.

i took the code from another web, but im not able to make it work. i think there is some problem with my getelementbyid function.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
      <script  type="text/javascript">
        var initialDate = new Date(2012, 11, 1); // Dec 1st 2012
        var now = Date.now();
        var difference = now - initialDate;
        var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);

        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = daysSince.toString();
      </script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <p id="show"></p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the script is ran before the p tag with id='show' was created in the DOM. Put the script after the p tag and it works!

Like so:

```html
    <html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
      </head>
      <body>
        <p id="show"></p>
        <script  type="text/javascript">
          var initialDate = new Date(2012, 11, 1); // Dec 1st 2012
          var now = Date.now();
          var difference = now - initialDate;
          var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
          var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);

          document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = daysSince.toString();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, wasnt aware of thar. is my first time working with js

Comment: No problem Paulo! If you except the answer it will allow for others to find the answer in the future too!

Answer (score 0):

Just put your script at the end of the code, before `</body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <p id="show"></p>
            <script  type="text/javascript">
                var initialDate = new Date(2012, 11, 1); // Dec 1st 2012
                var now = Date.now();
                var difference = now - initialDate;
                var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);

                document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = daysSince.toString();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```